# How to make a command that will be executed if at least one type of a certain block is present in the world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need to make a command so that I can place, for example, a block of white wool in the world and this command will be executed under this block:

```
summon minecraft:item ~ ~ ~ {Tags:["123"],PickupDelay:32767,Item:{id:"minecraft:apple",Count:1b}}
```

minecraft version: 1.20.1

I don't understand why this doesn't work:

```
execute if block ~ ~ ~ minecraft:white_wool run summon minecraft:item ~ ~-1 ~ {Tags:["123"],PickupDelay:32767,Item:{id:"minecraft:apple",Count:1b}}
```

or

```
execute unless block ~ ~ ~ minecraft:white_wool run summon minecraft:item ~ ~-1 ~ {Tags:["123"],PickupDelay:32767,Item:{id:"minecraft:apple",Count:1b}}
```

Comment: this looks like it'll summon underneath the command block. have you tried using the `at` keyword?

Comment: Maybe checking a block that is present in the world will require player interaction with it. Or simply, you can check when players place this block by using this scoreboard `minecraft.used:minecraft.white_wool` .

Comment: It also seems that your command only checks the block that player *standing* on